# Return two arrays from a c function by using WSTP library to Mathematica in a special manner

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp

I have two arrays. The first one is an array of integers, and the second one is an array of doubles. I want to write a ***c*** function to return these arrays by using ***WSTP*** library to Mathematica. I know that I can return these arrays in this way:

```
void Func()
{
   ...
   WSPutInteger32List(stdlink, arrayOfIntegers, arrayOfIntegersLength);
   WSPutReal64List(stdlink, arrayOfDoubles, arrayOfDoublesLength);
}
```

By using this way, the output which is shown in Mathematica is not what I want. I want to show the arrays in Mathematica as follows

```
out[command's number]: {{arrayOfIntegers}, {arrayOfDoubles}}
```

Can you guide me?

Comment: The answer should be familiar to you by now. Use `Manual` return. To return multiple results, you simply return a `List` of them. Use `WSPutFunction` to create the list.  Is this sufficient information for you to do it?

Comment: The key is that you are only allowed to return *one* expression. What's wrong with your code is that you are putting two expressions on the link. Wrapping them up in a list makes them into a single expression.

Comment: @Szabolcs If it is possible, please write its code by using WSPutFunction

Comment: You'll find the answers to most of your questions posted so far in this tutorial: http://edenwaith.com/development/tutorials/mathlink/ML_Tut.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the code you show, you are trying to return two expressions. This is not possible. A function can only return a single expression.  The solution: wrap up the two results into a single expression by placing them into a list.

So, it is not possible to return `a, b`, but it is possible to return `{a,b}` instead.

You need to use [PutFunction](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/c/WSPutFunction.html) to achieve this.

Example code:

```c
WSPutFunction(stdlink, "List" /* head */, 2 /* two elements in the list */);
  WSPutInteger32List(stdlink, arrayOfIntegers, arrayOfIntegersLength);
  WSPutReal64List(stdlink, arrayOfDoubles, arrayOfDoublesLength);
```

Given your interest in WSTP, I strongly suggest you read through [this tutorial](http://edenwaith.com/development/tutorials/mathlink/ML_Tut.pdf).  Some things are outdated, but most of it is still relevant. Do read *at least* up to section 1.5 (inclusive), and preferably all of the 1st chapter.