# Send an error message from a c function by using WSTP library

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp

Consider that ***Func*** is a function written in ***c*** language by using ***WSTP*** library. In some situations, it can return an error to Mathematica.

```
void Func()
{
   ...
   WSPutSymbol(stdlink, "$Failed");
}
```

In addition to show a $Failed message, I want to show an error message (a red colored message). How can I do this?

Comment: Section 1.6 in the tutorial I suggested to you.

Comment: Here is an example of sending a message from a library: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6527191/4712538

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [tutorial](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/174/) I [suggested](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/180962/12) to you has a complete example. See section 1.6. Please read through the entire first chapter.

---

Here's a copy of the code from there:

In your template file, ensure that both argument passing and return are set to `Manual`, then add the following:

```
:Evaluate: AddTwo::ovflw = "The sum cannot fit into a C long type."
```

A modification of the `addtwo` example:

```c
void addtwo(void) {
   long i, j, sum;
   MLGetLongInteger(stdlink, &i);
   MLGetLongInteger(stdlink, &j);
   sum = i + j;
   if(i>0 && j>0 && sum<0 || i<0 && j<0 && sum>0) {
     MLEvaluate(stdlink, "Message[AddTwo::ovflw]");
     MLNextPacket(stdlink);
     MLNewPacket(stdlink);
     MLPutSymbol(stdlink, "$Failed");
   } else {
     MLPutLongInteger(stdlink, sum);
   }
}
```