# How to use both WSTP and MathLink libraries?

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp

We are in the process of writing a Mathematica library by using C language and WSTP library. We encountered a lot of problems like [sending a message from C to Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180985/send-an-error-message-from-a-c-function-by-using-wstp-library/180987#180987), [implementing an argument which is an array of strings in C](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180841/how-i-can-implement-an-argument-which-is-an-array-of-string-by-using-wstp-librar/180844#180844), and so on. These problems cannot be solved by using WSTP library, and we need to use MathLink library. I should be noted that we have written a large portion of our library, and we cannot migrate from WSTP to MathLink now.

> Question: I need to use both of `wstp.h` and `mathlink.h` libraries. Is there a way to use these two libraries in a project?

Comment: This question is based on a misunderstanding. "WSTP" and "MathLink" are the very same thing. There is *zero* functional difference. The only difference is in whether functions names start with a `WS` or an `ML`.

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of [What is the difference between MathLink and WSTP? Which one should I use?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/91558/12).

Comment: @H.H My answer might be useless. I was under the impression you are writing a "LibraryLink" and you need to send more complex arguments to your functions. It seems I was wrong. Can you please go through the post linked by Henrik and Szabolcs and tell if this solves your problem?